# Charging for apps. in the software center?

Tags: desktop-apps

I have been wanting to switch from Windows to Linux, but I noticed Ubuntu software center charges for some apps. I thought Linux/Ubuntu is a free Open Source!

Comment: Free software as in freedom, not free beer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software

Comment: Closely related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/625002/how-can-open-source-programs-make-money/625012#625012

Answer (score 0):

This is a bid discussion, first you shall know what is the meaning of open source and what is meaning of free. Plus you should have some knowledge on licenses and different types of licences.

In simple words:

[What is open source software?](http://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source)

> Open source software is software whose source code is available for
>   modification or enhancement by anyone.
>
> "Source code" is the part of software that most computer users don't
>   ever see; it's the code computer programmers can manipulate to change
>   how a piece of software—a "program" or "application"—works.
>   Programmers who have access to a computer program's source code can
>   improve that program by adding features to it or fixing parts that
>   don't always work correctly.

[What do you mean by Free?](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html)

> A program is free software if the program's users have the four
>   essential freedoms:
>
> 1. The freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose (freedom
>      0).
> 2. The freedom to study how the program works, and change it so it does
>      your computing as you wish (freedom 1). Access to the source code is
>      a precondition for this.
> 3. The freedom to redistribute copies so you can help your neighbor
>      (freedom 2).
> 4. The freedom to distribute copies of your modified versions to others
>      (freedom 3). By doing this you can give the whole community a chance
>      to benefit from your changes. Access to the source code is a
>      precondition for this.

[Selling Free Software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.en.html)

Many people believe that the spirit of Free software is that you should not charge money for distributing copies of software, or that you should charge as little as possible—just enough to cover the cost. This is a **misunderstanding**.

> The word “free” has two legitimate general meanings; it can refer
>   either to freedom or to price. When we speak of “free software”, we're
>   talking about freedom, not price. (Think of “free speech”, not “free
>   beer”.) Specifically, it means that a user is free to run the program,
>   change the program, and redistribute the program with or without
>   changes.
>
> Free programs are sometimes distributed gratis, and sometimes for a
>   substantial price. Often the same program is available in both ways
>   from different places. The program is free regardless of the price,
>   because users have freedom in using it.
>
> Nonfree programs are usually sold for a high price, but sometimes a
>   store will give you a copy at no charge. That doesn't make it free
>   software, though. Price or no price, the program is nonfree because
>   its users are denied freedom.
>
> Since free software is not a matter of price, a low price doesn't make
>   the software free, or even closer to free. So if you are
>   redistributing copies of free software, you might as well charge a
>   substantial fee and make some money. Redistributing free software is a
>   good and legitimate activity; if you do it, you might as well make a
>   profit from it.