# Open Source Alternatives to 123D Catch

Tags: software-recommendation

[123D Catch](http://www.123dapp.com/catch) is an app for Windows, OSX and Android that lets a user turn a series of photographs into a 3D model (a process known as photogrammetry).

Is there an alternative, preferably with a GUI, available for Linux/Ubuntu?

Comment: VisualSFM is open source

Comment: @Maythux it isn't. Check the README. Licence says free for non commercial use and no GPL or similar licence is mentioned

Comment: Please note that non free doesn't mean it's not open source, this is a discussion. Read my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/635016/150504

Comment: It is not open source as Changchang Wu himself states in the next link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vsfm/wjCGW6nzLyc VisualSFM makes use of open sourced programs like siftGPU though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enjoy the open source realm, you can find many such apps:

- [Agisoft Photoscan](http://www.agisoft.com/): Here's a [tutorial](http://www.agisoft.com/pdf/PS_1.0.0%20-Tutorial%20%28BL%29%20-%203D-model.pdf). (not open source, thanks for [@Yomismo](https://askubuntu.com/users/304272/yomismo)'s comment)
- [VisualSFM](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/install.html): Here's a [tutorial](http://www.iafsm.org/resources/Opensourcetoolspart3.pdf).(not open source,thanks for [@Yomismo](https://askubuntu.com/users/304272/yomismo) & [@hellocatfood](https://askubuntu.com/users/6689/hellocatfood) comments)
- [Python Photogrammetry Toolbox](http://184.106.205.13/arcteam/ppt.php): Here's a [tutorial](http://arc-team-open-research.blogspot.com.br/2012/12/how-to-make-3d-scan-with-pictures-and.html).
- [openMVG](http://imagine.enpc.fr/~moulonp/openMVG/): Here's a [tutorial](https://smathermather.wordpress.com/tag/openmvg/).

Moreover you can use a GNU/Linux distribution called [ArcheOS](http://www.archeos.eu/).

> ArcheOS is the acronym of Archeological Operating System. It is a
>   GNU/Linux live distribution built for archaeological aims. At the
>   moment a new version (5.0 codename “Theodoric”) based on Debian
>   “Wheezy” is under development.

You can use the 3D applications that suit your needs.

[image]

Comment: Just one note: Photoscan is not Open Source. Of the other three I have tried VisualSFM with great results (eventhough it is not Open Source either but it is free to use for none comercial use). You can use 3 different sift alternatives (siftGPU, Lowe's sift and vlfeat) you may also be able to use asift which seems to give great results, but you will have to tweak the files so that VisualSFM can use them.

Comment: Thanks for compiling this list of programs! What is the advantage in using ArcheOS for the purpose of photogrammetry? Does it offer all (or a subset of) these programs out-of-the-box? Is it somehow specifically designed towards such purposes? This is not very clear from your post. (I can only see that there seems to be a menu item "Photogrammetry".)

Comment: It's just a distribution designed towards archaeological aims as described in the answer above, mostly you can find many tools dealing with images and scalar tools etc ...